# What is "*alarm*:*job.heartbeat*"?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, android-doze

I have found the reference to `"*alarm*:*job.heartbeat*"` in [JobSchedulerService.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/job/JobSchedulerService.java) and it appears that as the name of file suggests, `"*alarm*:*job.heartbeat*"`is related to scheduling of jobs and when I took the log of `dumpsys batterystats`, I found out that every 30 minutes, the phone come out of doze by this `"*alarm*:*job.heartbeat*"`. What is the role of `"*alarm*:*job.heartbeat*"` and can we configure the interval? (I'm rooted)

[image: dumpsys batterystats log]

Answer (score 1):

I think it is related to the android standby bucket. and maybe android 9 adaptive battery. and it is deeply integrated into the system. so it is not as simple as a system app uninstall. and the process is responsible for it is (system_server) .and if you delete it you will have to re-flash your ROM. and using [Battery Historian](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/battery-historian) `*alarm*:*job.heartbeat*`  is waking the device every 1 hour and half (90 minutes) but in my case, it does not wake the device out of 
Doze. see the image below [image: Untitgfhfhgfhfghfgled.png] if the doze is off there will be a gap. and there is a gap because I turned my screen on. my theory that the android system Schedule it to work to check for any change in the bucket and behave accordingly to it